# How can I enable auto match edges in GIMP?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

How can I enable auto match edges in gimp like photoshop?

I mean the pink lines in Photoshop. How do I activate this feature in GIMP?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You are talking about Smart Guides in Photoshop. There's no such functionality in GIMP, You can use normal guides and snap to guides, and  grids and snap to grid instead.